# Jquery Masonry infinite scroll page navigation in php

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-masonry

I am using masonry + infinite scroll to display a set of pages stored in database. I am not a professional programmer and hence am building it up on the demo provided. In the demo it uses a link to another html page (id=page-nav) which is loaded as infinite scroll to display additional elements

[ http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/infinite-scroll.html ]

```
 <nav id="page-nav">   <a href="../pages/2.html"></a> </nav>
```

I am using a database to build the same and am using the following code

```
<? 
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $summ = $row['summary'];
  $set_no = $row['set_no'];

*A*

  echo "<div class='box col1'>";
  echo " <p>";
  echo "<a href='$set_no.php' title='NA' ><img src='$set_no.jpg' alt='NA' /></a> Summary: $summ";
  echo "</p>";
  echo "</div>";

*B*

  }
?>
```

However as my database has more than 250 elements (set_no being a serial increment), I am trying to implement infinite scroll with 30 elements on one page. I have tried to put the following at `*A*` and `*B*` respectively but it seems not to be working.

```
*A*

 if ($set_no % 30 == 0)
  { echo "<nav id='page-nav'>";
  }

*B* 
  if ($set_no % 30 ==0)
  { echo "</nav>";
  }
```

Any clues how can I resolve the issue ?

Comment: exp_no is same as set_no. Sorry for that. I am new to stack overflow can I edit it in the post somehow ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/10457852/edit

Comment: Do you have some samples of set_no, and what they represent?

Comment: set_no are simple numbers {1,2,3,4,5....250} which I have stored in database.
database is created with 4-5 entries set_no is basically the index, other fields being summary, image, href location etc.

Comment: Can you post the SQL that gives rise to `$result` please?

Comment: Here it is 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `MYDB` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

the queries are running perfectly well. Removing *A* and *B* gives a 250 element webpage. I am trying to implement 30 element webpage with infinite scroll.

Comment: Yup, I see what you are trying to achieve but I can't see how infiniteScroll does its pagination. I thought your SQL might help but infiniteScroll appears to be designed for use with Wordpress and loads from the same url every time without a query string. I'm confused.